# How can I add more parameters to the selector called by addTarget:action:forControlEvents:?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

When the button pressed, I want to push a new view, and I need to pass an `NSDictionary` object to new `DetailViewController` ,so the method looks like this:

```
-(void)displayCourseDetail:(NSDictionary*)dictionary{
    self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc]init]initWithDictionary:dictionary];
    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But I don't know how to pass an `NSDictionary` by this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayCourseDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The button was created in code because it's dynamic.

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame=CGRectMake(_StartX+day*_ButtonWidthWorkday, _StartY+course*_ButtonHeightNormal, _ButtonWidthWorkday-_ButtonMargin, _ButtonHeightNormal-_ButtonMargin);
```

How can I pass the `NSDictionary` object to specific view controller when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in the action method, pass the dictionary:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender{
    ...
    [self performSelector:@selector(displayCourseDetail:) withObject:yourDictionary];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add any parameters to the selector called by `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.  You need to do some logic to create the dictionary from scratch or get a reference to an existing one in `displayCourseDetail:`.  Once you have that, you can pass it to `initWithDictionary` the same way you are currently passing the method argument.

I can't help you without seeing a lot more of your code, but I would imagine that however you are accessing the dictionary when creating the `button` would work if moved into `displayCourseDetail:` too.

I noticed that when you are making a `DetailViewController` you call both `init` and `initWithDictionary:` which is very likely not correct.  You should use `initWithDictionary:` only.

Comment: Ya,u'r right.I @property a NSDictionary object reference to current one,and passing it in displayCourseDetail: ,it's done.

Comment: I try to use initWithDictionary: only ,but it can't work.so I think UIViewController haven't this method, I can't override.

Comment: `UIViewController` definitely doesn't have that method, I assumed you implemented it yourself in `DetailViewController`.

Comment: Yes,I sure I implemented `-(id)initWithDictionary:` in DetailViewController.but I can't initial like this: `[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithDictionary];`,xcode will report a error

Comment: You're missing the dictionary argument.  It should be `[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithDictionary:someDictionaryReference]`